# How to print just the table data element using JavaScript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to print a particular table data element.

The table structure is as follows.

```
| Table No | Table Code | Description | Action |
     4           8785        abc         Print
     5           7463        cde         Print
     6           5645        fgh         Print
```

I want to print the elements of just the first two columns(Table No,Table Code) of a row when I click on the Print link.

The javascript code below prints the whole row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Print(a) {
        alert("heloo");
        var row = $(a).closest("tr").clone(true);
        var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0", ",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');
        var table = $("[id*=tableCodeTable]").clone(true);
        $("tr", table).not($("tr:first-child", table)).remove();
        table.append(row);
        $("tr td:last,tr th:last", table).remove();
        var dv = $("<div />");
        dv.append(table);
        printWin.document.write(dv.html());
        printWin.document.close();
        printWin.focus();
        printWin.print();
        printWin.close();
    }
</script>
```

The html code for print link

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="Print(this)">Print</a>
```

The html code for table

```
<table border="2px" id="tableCodeTable" class="table">
  <tr>
        <th>
            Table No
        </th>
        <th>
            Table Code
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>         
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
 <% foreach (var item in Model.Mapping)
 {%>   
   <tr id="<%=item.Id%>">

        <td id="no_<%=item.Id%>" class="two">
             <input type="hidden" value=" <%=item.Id%>"/>
            <%=item.TableNo%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=item.TableCode%>
        </td>
      <td id="dc_<%=item.Id%>" class="twoo"> 
           <%=item.Description%>
       </td>          
        <td>      
             <a href="javascript:;" onclick="Print(this)">Print</a>
        </td>
  </tr>            
 <% } %>
 </tbody>   
</table>
```

How can I print just those two elements? Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two ways of doing this:

1. Create a separate CSS style-sheet that only shows what you want to print. Rest is set as `display: none;`

   Link that CSS with `media="print"`. So, it will be used only while printing. For rest of the columns and other HTML elements set `display: none;` in this CSS. It will apply automatically.
2. Another way is to open a new window using `window.open()` that only shows what you want to print and calls `window.print()` after a decent `timeout` of say 100 msec. so that the data gets loaded properly before initiating the print process.

You may use another approach for this, which is even simpler. Print without using setTimeOut

```
var prnWin = window.open(somePath);
prnWin.onload = function() {
    prnWin.print();
};
```

> There could be other ways too to accomplish what you want to do. But I think the 1st approach mentioned by me would work best for you.

Comment: Could you please be more specific with the first approch? do i have to use `display:none` in `<td>` which i dont want to print? And how to use `timeout` ?

Comment: @RohanKhandelwal, create a new CSS file, say `print.css`. Set `display: none;` for all those items which you don't want to print. For particular `td` items you may have to assign them `class` and set their `display` property in the print.css file.

Comment: You don't have to use `timeout` with option #1. Use it with option #2. You have to use one of the two options, not both. Check the code snippet that I have pasted for approach #2. With this you don't have to use timeout.

Comment: Hi @RohanKhandelwal, did the solution work for you or you need some help?

Comment: this is what i have done. its not working.

print.css code  

    `.dont {  
    display: none;  
    }`  

table code  
    `<table class="table">  
              
    <th class="dont">  
                Action  
    </th>  
      
    <td class="dont">  
    </td>`  

Javascript code where i am calling the print.css  

     `function PrintElem(elem) {
                Popup($(elem).html());
            }  

    function Popup(data) {
               
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet"href="print.css"  type="text/css" />');
  }`  

is the print.css statement correct?

Comment: If you are using the print.css approach, you don't have to open a new window. Just `<link />` it like an ordinary css with `media="print"` and it will work automatically. You don't need to have anything in the JS, etc. Just the css would do. Just add `class="dont" in the HTML code. This would not affect anything on the screen HTML but will check in the print version.

Comment: where do i include `media="print"`?

Comment: See this example - `<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sometheme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
</head>` - the 2nd css is for media print

Comment: so i dont have to call the onclick function when i click on the print button? `<button class="btn btn-primary" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')">Print Table</button>`

Comment: If you create the print.css properly, all you have to do is onclick of the button call `window.print();` and it will print all the visible html elements. The page will also print if you do normal CTRL+P/Print command. To check the effect of print.css see Print Preview from your browser.

Comment: when i click on the print button, it shows the complete page in the print preview .
i have used this code `<button class="btn btn-primary" value="Print Div" onclick="window.print();">Print Table</button>`

Comment: Have you applied the print.css file as mentioned in my previous comment? In print.css you need to hide each and every html element which you don't want to print. You may copy your default css to print.css and remove all the styling and apply `display: none;` for such items. And add a few classes or ids like `dont`.

Comment: your solution does work when i include the print.css file in the master page. but it doesn't work when i click on the print button without including the print.css file in the master page.

Comment: You will have to include the print.css in the master page or any new window that you open

Comment: i want to remove the columns when the print preview page gets loaded